# Include data in a table looking in every insert if there is a match with the table values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to insert data from one table into another, but this insert must look into the table which receives data to determine if there is a match or not, and if it is, don't insert new data.

So, i have the next tables *(NODE_ID refers to values in NODE1 and NODE2, think about lines with two nodes everyone)*:

```
Table A:
| ARC | NODE1 | NODE2 | STATE |
| x   |  1    |  2    |   A   |
| y   |  2    |  3    |   A   |
| z   |  3    |  4    |   B   |

Table B:
| NODE_ID| VALUE |
|    1   |   N   |
|    2   |   N   |
|    3   |   N   |
|    4   |   N   |
```

And want the next result, that relates NODE_ID with ARCS and write in the result table the value of STATE from ARCS table, **only one result for each NODE**, because if not, i would have more than one row for the same NODE:

```
Table C result:
| NODE_ID| STATE |
|    1   |   A   |
|    2   |   A   |
|    3   |A(or B)|
```

I tried to do this with CASE statement with EXISTS, IF , and NVL2() and so on in the select but have no result at this time.

Any idea about how could i write this query?

Thank you very much for your help

---

Ok guys, i edit my message to explain how i did it finally, i've also changed a little bit my first message to make it more clear to undestand because we had problems with that.

So finally i used this query, that @mathguy introduced to me:

```
merge into Table_C c
   using (select distinct b.NODE_ID as nodes, a.STATE
          from Table_A a, Table_B b
          where (b.NODE_ID=a.NODE1 or b.NODE_ID=a.NODE2) s
   on (s.nodes=c.NODE_ID)

when not matched then
  insert (NODE_ID, STATE)
  values (s.nodes, s.STATE)
```

That's all

Comment: How is table B related to all of this?

Comment: table B is related with NODE_ID value with NODE1 or NODE2. Think about lines with two nodes everyone.

Comment: Look here, this is what you need:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: I still don't understand table B, and most importantly, what role it plays in your specific problem. I can see how you can go from table A to table C directly, without needing table B at all. Right? If not, then your explanation needs to be expanded - where in the whole process do we need to know that table B even exists?

Comment: mathguy: your are right, but I simplyfied the problem to exclude other non relevant data. The  real problem here is little bit more complicated to explain here. Table A and B need to be connected by other columns not explained here.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `insert`, but often when you update one table with values from another, the `merge` statement is more powerful (more flexible).

```
merge into table_c c
  using ( select arc, min(state) as state from table_a group by arc ) s
  on (s.arc = c.node_id)
when not matched then insert (node_id, state)
  values (s.arc, s.state)
;
```

*Thanks to @Boneist and @ThorstenKettner for pointing out several syntax errors (now fixed).*

Comment: thank you for your help! Nice solution. But i think maybe my question was not clear at all because, in table c, values of "s.arc" are not the same as "node_id", i mean "node_id" in table_B refers to values in "node1" and "node2" in table_A. Still i'll use your solution statement of merge

Comment: @Albert - I suspected as much, which is why I asked for clarification. I see the `node1` and `node2` columns in table A, and I see table B; I don't see any explanation of HOW they should be related (perhaps a join, but without an explanation I can't tell). Try to use the MERGE statement as described here (and google "Oracle MERGE" and see the documentation, with examples) and try to solve the problem yourself. Feel free to write back if you run into additional problems. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If table C does not yet exist, use a create select statement:

```
create table c as select arc as node_id, state from a;
```

In case there can be duplicate arc (not shown in your sample) you'd need aggregation:

```
create table c as select arc as node_id, min(state) as state from a group by arc;
```

Comment: I think the problem was really about inserting over time (the OP talks about looking in the receiving table - table C - to see if there is a match or not).